# How to change the path before injection

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-contrib-connect, grunt-wiredep

**Is it possible to change the path of the injected file before injection occurs?**

I am using Grunt/Bower/Connect/Wiredep, and my directory structure is:

```
www
|- dev-dist/
|- node_modules/
|- src/
|- vendor/
|- bower.json
|- Gruntfile.js
|- package.json
```

(Note: in my .bowerrc file I've added `directory: vendor`)

When I run the custom task `grunt serve:dev` it will create the directory `dev-dist`, I will then copy my index.html (only) to the folder, after which I run the task `wiredep`.

After running `wiredep`, the src paths to my dependencies are all prefixed with '../vendor/'.  The problem is that when I run `connect` I have the option `base: ['vendor', 'dev-dist', 'src']`.  When everything is served, the relative path to vendor doesn't make any sense because the vendor dir is already served at the root.

**Is there a way I can modify the path to the injected files before wiredep injects them?** (So I can remove the '../vendor')

What I would like to have happen is from the same workspace be able to run `grunt serve:*` and specify dev/stage/prod environments.  This is why I did not want to serve the whole www directory.

**Is there a way to exclude folders from being served in connect?** (So instead of specifying base:[...], I can just exclude the stage-dist / prod-dist folders)

Thanks,

JD

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `ignorePath` with a regular expression

`ignorePath: /\.\.\//,`

from the `wiredep` to remove the `../` from the path that is getting injected. The configuration details are available over here https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#configuration

I haven't used connect yet, so I am not sure of your second part of the question.